# `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` works well with the first line of my text but doesn't center my 2nd line. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make some kind of a notification/message box giving players hints to advance the gameplay, here is the code

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
  width: 320, height: 200,
  scene: {
    create: create
  }
});
function create() {
  let noti_bg = this.add.rectangle(160, 100, 200, 120, 0x000000, .5);
  let noti_txt = this.add.text(0, 0, 'Magic is not ready yet\n\nwait a sec');
  Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(noti_txt, noti_bg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

`Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` works well with the first line of my text but doesn't center my 2nd line. How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` just aligns single GameObjects. Both lines of text are in the *same* GameObject `noti_txt`.

If you want to align both textlines, you could use the `align` property of the text GameObject, on creating it.  `{ align: 'center' }`
*(Or after creation with the property `setStyle` here a [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.html#setStyle))*

**Here the adapted Code:**

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
  width: 320, height: 200,
  scene: {
    create: create
  }
});
function create() {
  let noti_bg = this.add.rectangle(160, 100, 200, 120, 0x000000, .5);
  let noti_txt = this.add.text(0, 0, 'Magic is not ready yet\n\nwait a sec', { align: 'center' });
  Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(noti_txt, noti_bg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Alternatively / Extra**:
I would only recommended it, if you are reusing text blocks *(or dramatic effect)*, you could split the text, into two GameObjects.

But for that to work you would also have use the function `Phaser.Display.Align.To.BottomCenter`:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
  width: 320, height: 200,
  scene: {
    create: create
  }
});
function create() {
  let noti_bg = this.add.rectangle(160, 100, 200, 120, 0x000000, .5);
  let noti_txt1 = this.add.text(0, 0, 'Magic is not ready yet');
  let noti_txt2 = this.add.text(0, 0, 'wait a sec');

  // extra visual effect
  this.tweens.add({
    targets: noti_txt2 ,
    alpha: 0,
    ease: 'Power1',
    duration: 1000,
    yoyo: true,
    repeat: -1,
  });
  Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(noti_txt1, noti_bg);
  // Just adding a minor horizontal offset
  Phaser.Display.Align.To.BottomCenter(noti_txt2, noti_txt1, 0, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```